# Email forwarding to Gmail accounts instead of maintaining a mail server?

Tags: web-hosting, email, gmail

I want to set up 4-5 email addresses on my newly purchased domain (from `namecheap.com`), for team size of just 2-3 people. But I really don't want to maintain my own mail server.  I  don't have the experience and I want to avoid the expenses involved.   Maybe I could have kept the mail server alongside my webapp on the web server, but I want to avoid that as well.

So I came across a workaround option to forward the emails. Thus I could setup email forwarding from NameCheap's management console to my free Gmail accounts. So all my emails would come to Gmail account, convenient & familiar interface as well free.

Are there any serious drawbacks of this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me drawbacks of this approach is becoming more and more dependable on Google overall. We are already Google products ourselves. Google sell our data to data brokers, pass to NSA, use it to push pestilent ads, etc. We give away our privacy a little each day. And in this case it is not about your personal box for spam but a business email account.

Answer (score 3):

One disadvantage is that sending email from Gmail would not appear to come from your domain name.  It would come from the Gmail address.

There is a partial workaround.  You could [set the "reply to" email address in the Gmail account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7991).  But the instructions say that it will only change where replies go, not where the mail appears to come from:

> Responses to messages you send with an alternate reply-to address are delivered to that address. Keep in mind that your Gmail address still appears in the From: field.

This could become an issue as you try to build a brand.  It is more professional and better for the brand for your emails sent from your company email address.

Comment: Providing you can receive the email to gmail you can set it up to send _From_ that address as well. Although if you are using Google's SMTP servers (the default) then the receiving email client _might_ state that it is sent "via _your gmail account_". To remove the "via" notice (the result of a Sender: header) you can change it to use your own SMTP server (although namecheap may not provide this without further cost).

Comment: The problem with using your own SMTP server is that you risk having emails you've sent ending up in customers' spam folders. I've been there - that's why I decided to use Amazon's Simple Mail Service for sending automated emails from my domain. It's very cheap and reliable.

Comment: For now, I'll be using the free one year plan from Namecheap which provides me with 1 mailbox with 1 alias(I wish I could add more aliases there..). Try to work with that since right now I am the only single user. When more users are needed I'll probably go with Rackspace/Amazon or other email hosting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) But now is not "free", and you have to pay if you want to use "email services" from Google GMail. it says in [Google Apps Pricing](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html)   you have to pay $5/user/month or  $10/user/month if you want to pay "more". You can try it for free for 30 days if you want.